# Can a daughter give zakat to her mother ...?

Tags: zakat, parents

if a mother is financial week and other side a daughter is financially strong then is this right to support her mother and give her money as zakat, because zakat start from your family.is this right or not....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your mother is poor, then it is obligatory for you to spend on her anyways, you can not combine and eliminate this obligation with Zakat.  Zakat can not be given to parents or children, but can be given to brothers and sisters and other relatives on whom it is not obligatory to spend upon.

https://islamqa.info/en/answers/81122/it-is-not-permissible-to-give-zakaah-to-one-on-whom-you-are-obliged-to-spend

Answer (score 0):

We have people and relatives who are poor; For example, if our parents are poor, or some parents ask and say that our children and grandchildren are poor, can we pay zakat al-fitr to these people?
These people are called obligatory alimony, that is, they are people who, if they are poor, we have to provide for them in terms of livelihood and expenses.
According to all the authorities of imitation, we cannot pay our zakat al-fitr to the people who are our obligatory alimony; That is, if our parents or children are poor, we can not give zakat al-fitr to these people, it does not matter if this single girl and boy are married, live with their parents or have an independent life, live in another city, no One of these cases is no different in paying zakat al-fitr.
If these people are poor and we have the financial means, it is obligatory to provide them financially; But they cannot be helped with the money of zakat al-fitr and atonement, but there is no problem in paying zakat al-fitr to aunts, uncles, brothers and sisters, brides and grooms.

Ref: https://www.ana.press/news/385556/